# Expose kubernetes cluster ip to my local lan

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

My local lan lives on 192.168.0.0/24. I've set up a kubernetes cluster using all the defaults. I spun up a unifi controller image, the pod is on 10.244.224.69. I also exposed this with a cluster ip 10.106.239.158. Locally on the kubernetes host, I can hit port 8443 and 8080 fine on both IP addresses. But from a PC on 192.168.0.0/24 of course not as there's no route. What is the recommended method to reverse proxy into the cluster ip from my lan? Ideally I want to create a new IP address in 192.168.0.0/24. The new lan address should belong to the ingress controller, and I'm assuming the ingress controller also then gets a 10. address that can reach the cluster ip. I don't mind rebuilding the cluster, just looking for ideas and best practice. Thanks

Comment: I think all that's needed is an inbound NAT on a new virtual interface on the host server. The NAT should route to a load balancer. Will update when I have time to implement.

Answer (score 0):

NodePort service is the simplest way to expose a service within your Kubernetes cluster. It assigns a random port (higher than 30000) to the service on each worker node and makes it accessible from any host on your LAN using that port.

This document might be useful for you.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Comment: The trouble is how to open my entirely default kubernetes cluster to my 192.168 range. It appears is is an ingress I need, but can I create one with a fixed IP in 192 and a dynamic in 10 which can proxy to the nodeport/clusterip/etc?